# How to change location of boxplots along axis in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

`pgfplots` draws boxplots equally spaced along the axis (x axis in my example below). How can I draw the boxplots at different locations along the axis? E.g., the example below the distance between the second and third boxes would be three times the distance between the first two. The boxes would need to all have the same width.

Is there an option that I'm missing? Do I need to go back and customize some of the code that's floating around from before `pgfplots` supported boxplots directly?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        boxplot/draw direction=y,
        xtick={1,2,3},
        xticklabels={1,2,5}]
      \addplot+[boxplot prepared={
          lower whisker=2.5, lower quartile=4, median=8.5, upper quartile=12, upper whisker=15},] coordinates {};
      \addplot+[boxplot prepared={
          lower whisker=2.5, lower quartile=4, median=8.5, upper quartile=12, upper whisker=15},] coordinates {};
      \addplot+[boxplot prepared={
          lower whisker=2.5, lower quartile=4, median=8.5, upper quartile=12, upper whisker=15},] coordinates {};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `draw position=<val>` option to specify the location on x-axis.

## Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
% \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        boxplot/draw direction=y,
        % xtick={1,2,3},
        % xticklabels={1,2,5},
      ]
      \addplot+[boxplot prepared={
          lower whisker=2.5, lower quartile=4, median=8.5, upper quartile=12, upper whisker=15},] coordinates {};
      \addplot+[boxplot prepared={
          lower whisker=2.5, lower quartile=4, median=8.5, upper quartile=12, upper whisker=15},] coordinates {};
      \addplot+[boxplot prepared={draw position=5,
          lower whisker=2.5, lower quartile=4, median=8.5, upper quartile=12, upper whisker=15},] coordinates {};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I guess I missed it because although it is listed in the manual, there's no actual example of its use!